# CSS animation is not reaching to top

Tags: css

Can you pinpoint what's wrong with my CSS code? The animations won't reach the top of the page when I'm viewing [this page](http://rogerdecastro.tk/portfolio/Animated_Login_Page/) on a 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add your relevant code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right at the bottom of your CSS file you have

```
@-webkit-keyframes bgobjects {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
```

Looks like you're only moving the objects 700px, so that's why they're not reaching the top. Try increasing (or should I say, decreasing) this value more, or maybe try percentages. If it's still not working, create a simplified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can assist you further.

Note that you have two similar blocks like the above CSS - you'll need to change the values in both of these blocks (should be identical, other than the -webkit prefix), as they will apply to different browsers.